# Any tips on simplifying my code?

Tags: sql

I am writing sql for the requirement:
Get closing stock if location > 10 
add 3 lines with location value 800, 810 and closing stock values for these new records would be aggregated closing stock for all locations.
Any clues to simplify. I am specifically looking at ways of not reading aggregated closing stock multiple times.

```
SELECT 
    I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE
    ,I.LOCATION as store_id
    , I.SKU
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_QTY) as closing_stock_qty
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_COST_AMT) as closing_stock_cost_amt
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_RETAIL_AMT) as closing_stock_retail_amt
FROM DAILY_CLOSING_STOCK I 
join ASSORTMENT_SEASON asrt_sea
on I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE>=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_START_DATE and 
   I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE<=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_END_DATE
where asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_CODE = 'S17' and I.LOCATION>10 and 
   (closing_stock_qty <> 0 or closing_stock_cost_amt <> 0 or 
    closing_stock_retail_amt <> 0)
group by I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE, I."LOCATION", I.SKU
UNION 
SELECT 
    I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE
    ,'800' as store_id
    , I.SKU
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_QTY) as closing_stock_qty
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_COST_AMT) as closing_stock_cost_amt
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_RETAIL_AMT) as closing_stock_retail_amt
FROM DAILY_CLOSING_STOCK I 
join ASSORTMENT_SEASON asrt_sea
    on I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE>=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_START_DATE and             
    I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE<=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_END_DATE
where asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_CODE = 'S17' and (closing_stock_qty <> 0                     
    or closing_stock_cost_amt <> 0 or closing_stock_retail_amt <> 0)
group by I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE, I.SKU
UNION
SELECT 
    I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE
    ,'810' as store_id
    , I.SKU
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_QTY) as closing_stock_qty
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_COST_AMT) as closing_stock_cost_amt
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_RETAIL_AMT) as closing_stock_retail_amt
FROM DAILY_CLOSING_STOCK I 
join ASSORTMENT_SEASON asrt_sea
    on I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE>=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_START_DATE and             
    I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE<=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_END_DATE
where asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_CODE = 'S17' and (closing_stock_qty <> 0 
    or closing_stock_cost_amt <> 0 or closing_stock_retail_amt <> 0)
group by I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE, I.SKU
```

Comment: Skip the UNION's. Do one SELECT, with case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: That looks queer. `'800'/'810' as store_id`? You aren't aggregating over locations 800 or 810, but over *all* locations, so why pretend the store is 800 or 810? I don't understand what you want to do. Show sample data and desired result.

Comment: I don't understand how locations 800 and 810 constitute 3 lines.

Comment: Is `I.LOCATION` a number or a string? It seems to be a number (`I.LOCATION>10`), but why the quotes in `'800' as store_id` and `'810' as store_id` then?

Comment: Why `UNION`? This is a set operation removing duplicates. Are there duplicates to remove? Do you mean `UNION ALL`?

Comment: yes 800, 810.820 are virtual store_ids (they are not real). I would like to store sum of everything beside each of these virtual stores(800,810,820)

Comment: I wanted to add 820 as well but due to space constraint i removed it. If i added another block of code for 820 then it would be 3 lines. Sorry about confusion.

Comment: I tried to achieve it using sub query in a case statement but that was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "with as" to make a temp table that prevents you from joining the tables multiple times.

```
with t as (
select 
    I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE
    ,I.LOCATION
    , I.SKU
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_QTY) as closing_stock_qty
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_COST_AMT) as closing_stock_cost_amt
    ,sum(I.CLOSING_STOCK_RETAIL_AMT) as closing_stock_retail_amt

    FROM DAILY_CLOSING_STOCK I 
    join ASSORTMENT_SEASON asrt_sea
        on I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE>=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_START_DATE and             
        I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE<=asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_END_DATE
    where asrt_sea.ASSORTMENT_SEASON_CODE = 'S17' and (closing_stock_qty <> 0                     
        or closing_stock_cost_amt <> 0 or closing_stock_retail_amt <> 0)
    group by I.CLOSING_STOCK_DATE, I.SKU
)

select
    closing_stock_date,
    location store_id,
    sku,
    closing_stock_qty,
    closing_stock_cost_amt,
    closing_stock_retail_amt
from t
    where location>10
union
select
    closing_stock_date,
    '800' store_id,
    sku,
    closing_stock_qty,
    closing_stock_cost_amt,
    closing_stock_retail_amt
from t
select
    closing_stock_date,
    '810' store_id,
    sku,
    closing_stock_qty,
    closing_stock_cost_amt,
    closing_stock_retail_amt
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't going to be much more elegant ... You'd select the sums per location. From this data set you'd select all results for locations > 10 plus the totals over all locations cross joined with dummy locations 800, 810, 820.

```
with sums_per_location as
(
  select
    closing_stock_date,
    location as store_id,
    sku,
    sum(closing_stock_qty) as closing_stock_qty,
    sum(closing_stock_cost_amt) as closing_stock_cost_amt,
    sum(closing_stock_retail_amt) as closing_stock_retail_amt
  from daily_closing_stock dcs
  where exists
  (
    select *
    from assortment_season ass
    where dcs.closing_stock_date between ass.assortment_season_start_date
                                     and ass.assortment_season_end_date
    and ass.assortment_season_code = 'S17'
  )
  group by closing_stock_date, location, sku
)
, sums_for_all
(
  select
    closing_stock_date,
    store_ids.store_id,
    sku,
    sum(closing_stock_qty) as closing_stock_qty,
    sum(closing_stock_cost_amt) as closing_stock_cost_amt,
    sum(closing_stock_retail_amt) as closing_stock_retail_amt
  from sums_per_location
  cross join
  (
    select 800 as store_id
    union all
    select 810 as store_id
    union all
    select 820 as store_id
  ) store_ids
  group by closing_stock_date, sku
)
select * from sums_per_location where location > 10
union all
select * from sums_for_all;
```

I've cross joined before aggregation, to get the query a tad shorter. You can change this and join after Aggregation instead, which might even speed up the query.

Depending on your DBMS you may be able to replace the store_ids subquery with a more elegant values clause.